# Is algebraic geometry actually used in string theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, mathematical-physics, complex-geometry, string-theory

Many times I have heard string theorists say that string theory has a lot of algebraic geometry, but physicists seem to have identified complex differential geometry with algebraic geometry and obliviously those two fields are not the same.

Having searched some string theory notes and some papers and I saw that the techniques that are mostly used in string theory are cohomology, Chern classes, some category theory (which is not algebraic geometry, it's just used in it) and other techniques from differential geometry, but I wasn't able to find actual algebraic geometry techniques.
Perhaps there are some and I wasn't able to find them, so if you know of any, please give some references.

When I think algebraic geometry, I think of ideals, K-algebras, modules,algebraic stacks and other algebraic structures.

I understand that complex manifolds are also projective varieties and hence this could be the source of confusion but the techniques used in physics are purely from a differential geometry perspective not an algebraic one. And although I am not a physicist, I can't imagine how would things like ideals could be used in physics, but maybe that is due to my lack of understanding of physics.

So I want to ask why do physicists identify algebraic geometry with complex differential geometry?

Are techniques from algebraic geometry actually used in physics besides of derived categories?

Comment: By "actual AG techniques", what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Not that I really know, but isn't one of the main string theory statements an equivalence of categories between D-branes and the derived category of coherent sheaves on calabi-yau varietes? The latter category is certainly an algebro-geometric object.

Comment: @Con you are right, I forgot to mention that derived categories was the only object from algebraic geometry that I found to have applications in string theory, but in general most techniques are certainly differential geometric, I would like to know if there are other techniques from algebraic geometry used in string theory. The techniques I am looking for are those of algebraic flavor.

Comment: Other instances should be enumerative geometry/moduli theory as used in Gromov-Witten invariants and generally all the things related to mirror symmetry such as Hodge theory. While they certainyl also have symplectiv/analytic flavor, these are also theories within algebraic geometry. Not sure whether they live up to your desired examples though.

Comment: Note that studying complex manifolds (in particular Kähler manifolds and Hodge theory) is often considered "algebraic geometry". There are entire books on that topic, as *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris, or *Hodge theory and algebraic geometry 1+2* by Voisin. Other people prefer to call it "complex geometry" such as Huybrechts, and this stackexchange tag. Maybe this is where your confusion stems from?